# how configure apache virtualhost for two dotnet core 3.1 project?

Tags: apache2, virtualhost

I have two dotnet core 3.1 projects and two kestrel services. each works fine. when together, only the first one works.
[image]
Logs from first virtualhost.
[image]
Error Status Code: 404; Not Found
:)Sorry for my English.I need your help

Answer (score 0):

https://www.tecmint.com/change-apache-port-in-linux/
found the answer. I registered different ports and registered Listen  in /etc/apache2/port.conf